# What is best practice to insert SVN and version into war file?

Tags: maven

What is the recommended way to have the product version and svn url + revision embedded in the war file when working with Maven? Should I insert it in the pom during building, and if so, in which section? An example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To get those information you can use [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) to extract the svn version information. By using the properties you can put those values into `MANIFEST.MF` file or in a separated file which is filtered during the build process. Or you can create a Java class which contains such information via [templating-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/examples/source-filtering.html).

Answer (score 0):

alright

i have a version.properties file inside my java resources folder with the following content:

```
version.major=${version}
version.build=${env.SVN_REVISION}
version.date=${buildtime}
```

then, in my pom.xml i have this

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <buildtime>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildtime>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

and to read that information that has been filled in while building the .war, i got this properties field on the session bean:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{versionProperties}")
private Properties versionProperties;
```

and fill it by doing

```
private void initializeVersionData() {
    String mavenTimestamp = getVersionProperties().getProperty("version.date");
    // try to parse timestamp and reformat it
    try {
        // format of maven timestamp
        DateTimeFormatter mavenFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HHmm");
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(mavenTimestamp, mavenFormatter);
        // desired format
        DateTimeFormatter desiredFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        versionData.put("Datum", date.format(desiredFormatter));
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        logger.warn("couldnt parse time stamp, ignore if running locally");
        // fall back to maven timestamp
        versionData.put("Datum", mavenTimestamp);
    }
    versionData.put("Version", getVersionProperties().getProperty("version.major"));
    versionData.put("Build", getVersionProperties().getProperty("version.build"));
}
```

dont forget to generate getters.

to read the values from the sessionbean, i got this in my footer template file:

```
<div style="text-align:right;float:right;">
    &#169; 2016 it-processing AG
    <table style="width:120px;">
        <ui:repeat var="entry"
            value="#{sessionBean.version.entrySet().toArray()}"><br/>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <tr>
                    <td>#{entry.key}: </td>
                    <td>#{entry.value}</td>
                </tr>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
</div>
```

and that results in:

[image: result]

As for the svn url, you can hardcode it in the properties file.

**EDIT:**  Maybe one of those properties is only populated when you use jenkins as a build server, cant remember which one probably the buildnumber